# Visual studio unable to locate provisioning profiles for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to setup my environment to deploy my app to a real IPhone for testing because I dont want to work with simulators and etc. It apparently requires provisioning profiles. I dont have a paid apple developer account and I learned that it is not required. These are the steps I have done so far:

Open xcode on my mac go to Preferences> Accounts> Add new Apple ID. I added one of my apple IDs.

I then added a new project select a team and selected necessary options to create the project

I went to project propertiesi setup the iOS version.

I went to signing and enabled automaticly manage signing. It did something and created a certificate for me.

I deployed the app once to my phone which worked fine.

I later opened visual studio on my windows machine.

Paired my mac with my visual studio.

Went to info.plist and copied my bundle identifier from xcode to visual studio.

Enabled Manual provisioning but no developer profiles. Restarted VS but no luck

I basically followed this site
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows

I tried without selecting a specific provisioning profile (it was in developer (automatic))

It seemed to be going well until it gave this error

error MT1007: Failed to launch the application '/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App8/4ae6e8b79af6f5c06054809bff907c4f900782cdb32378817eb5bbdd1fa2e996/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone11.8-14.2/App8.app' on the device 'iPhone': Failed to launch the application 'com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.App8' on the device 'iPhone': Invalid Service Error (error: 0xe8000022)           0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. The site  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows showed illustrations of choosing specific provisional profiles

[image]

However I didn't get this kind of choosing

Mine had

Developer (automatic)

No profiles found (or something in english: my VS is not in english)

but apparently it is not required to choose the exact profile from VS. I was able to deploy the app by just compiling the app as usual (after following the steps of course). However there is a problem with launching the app which requires me to go to settings and trust my apple id or something which is not important.