# Iphone 13 Error When debugging IOS MAUI app from VS2022

Tags: visual-studio-code, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maui, visual-studio-2022

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error MT1007: Failed to launch the application '/Users/jaajitech/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TestApp/a3a8ad44c41ca6a9c305417349b408b3294f1a61364d707faf7d6c17f11ad8b5/bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone14.5-17.0.3/Test.app' on the device 'MyiPhone': Failed to launch the application 'xxx.xxxx.xxxx' on the device 'MyiPhone': Invalid Service Error (error: 0xe8000022)            0

How i have to resolve this error can you please guide me. what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Try to update to the latest Visual Studio version as well as XCode version. And you can follow up there: [VS 17.7.4 Error MT1007: Failed to launch the application Failed to launch the application on the device Invalid Service Error (error: 0xe8000022)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-1774----Error-MT1007:-Failed-to-lau/10473921?sort=active&topics=windows+10.0).

**Solution 2**

Do some operations on [Device provisioning for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/?view=net-maui-7.0), like this case: [Visual studio unable to locate provisioning profiles for Xamarin.iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65404238/visual-studio-unable-to-locate-provisioning-profiles-for-xamarin-ios).